# fetching data from mongodb in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I use the below code for getting data from mongodb

But the **userlist** is undefined in the .jade file

```
var db = monk('mongodb://UserName:Password@ds047342.mongolab.com:ds047342/UsersDB');



router.get('/userlist', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('Users');

    collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
        res.render('userlist', {
            "userlist": docs
        });
    });
});
```

code in the jade file

```
extends layout

    block content
        h1.
            User List
        ul
            each user, i in userlist
                li
                    a(href="mailto:#{user.EmailId}")= "name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to replicate your issue and successfully loaded users from my local collection, maybe you need to validate before rendering the page like

```
router.get('/userlist', function (req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var collection = db.get('Users');

    collection.find({}, {}, function (e, docs) {
        if (e){
            // something went wrong, render an error
        } else if (!docs) {
            // no users found, render a 404 maybe
        } else {
            // users found, render the list
            res.render('userlist', {
                "userlist": docs
            });
        }
    });
});
```